# Not able to disabled "href" link in Mozilla & Chrome

Tags: jquery

I am new to JavaScript and trying to modify code to make it cross-browser compatible. I am trying to create tabs (link), and by default `menu_item3` & `menu_item4` will be disabled. This code is not working on Mozilla & Chrome, only in IE. Below is the code being used to create tabs.

```
<ul>
   <li id="menu_item1" class="selectedtab">
       <a href="javascript:;" onclick="showTab(this)">
           <span style="color:black; font-weight: bold;">Report Options</span>
       </a>
   </li>
   <li id="menu_item2">
       <a href="javascript:;" onclick="showTab(this)">
           <span style="color:black; font-weight: bold;">Required Filters</span>
       </a>
   </li>
   <li id="menu_item3" class="disabled-state">
       <a href="javascript:;" onclick="showTab(this)" disabled='disabled'>
           <span style="color:black; font-weight: bold;">Optional Filters</span>
       </a>
   </li>
   <li id="menu_item4" class="disabled-state">
       <a href="javascript:;" onclick="showTab(this)" disabled='disabled'>
           <span style="color:black; font-weight: bold;">Confirmation</span>
       </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Below Code being used to disable link when page get loaded but it is not working in Mozilla & Chrome, only in IE.

```
var ItemA = document.getElementById('menu_item3').getElementTagName('a')[0];
ItemA.disabled=true;
```

Please suggest how to disable link in Mozilla & Chrome.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: The code you're asking about is the JavaScript `showTab()` function, yet you haven't included it in your question. We won't be able to help you much without seeing the portion of code that's not working.

Comment: @johnniebenson, are you able to see it ?

Comment: As @Santi pointed out, add your JS so we can see what's happening. Thanks

Comment: @Santi, if see code has already disabled='disabled' means when load the page these links are getting disabled but when we clicked showTab function get called.

Comment: `<a>` tags do not have a `disabled` attribute. The fact that it's working in any browser is surprising. What exactly are you trying to achieve by disabling a link that doesn't have an href anyway?

Comment: @Santi, menu_item3 & 4 are disabled by default when load and these are getting enabled when clicked a value in checkbox prompt.

Comment: ...Again, `<a>` **cannot** be disabled. There is no such thing as a "disabled" `<a>`. Please elaborate on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Santi, you are correct there is function written which is taking care but code is not working in mozilla and Chrome var menu_item_opt_filters =document.getElementById('menu_item3').getElementsByTagName('a')[0]; menu_item_opt_filters.disabled= true. Could you please tell how to cater this in mozilla

Answer (score 0):

Since `a` can't be `disabled` (in a standard way), consider going a more jQuery-ish route, and only apply the `onclick` handler to menu items without the `disabled-state` class.

This also cleans up your HTML, moving the `onclick` logic, etc. to JavaScript where it belongs.

```js
function showTab(el) {
  console.log("clicked " + el.parentNode.id);
}

// only apply to <a> elements, within .menuitems, that are children
// of <li> items without the disabled-state class
//
$('.menuitems').on('click', "li:not(.disabled-state) a", function() {
  showTab(this);
})
```

```css
.menuitems a span {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.disabled-state a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: default;
}
.menuitems .disabled-state a span {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class=menuitems>
  <li id="menu_item1" class="selectedtab">
    <a href="javascript:;">
      <span>Report Options</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu_item2">
    <a href="javascript:;">
      <span>Required Filters</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu_item3" class="disabled-state">
    <a href="javascript:;">
      <span>Optional Filters</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu_item4" class="disabled-state">
    <a href="javascript:;">
      <span>Confirmation</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```